# Check If String Is Valid XML with Jdom2

Tags: xml, jdom, jdom-2

What is the best way to check if a string is valid XML for Jdom2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put it in a try/catch block and parse it with JDOM 2..... then if you need to handle the JDOMException it is not valid.

rolfl